# How do I create an additional user on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu Core on my Raspberry Pi 3. After configuring it, I have now SSH access to the Pi using my Ubuntu account and a private key.

Now, I want to create an additional user, to simplify the SSH process (since I don't always have that private key around and simply want to login in with username + pass).

So I tried

```
sudo useradd myusername
```

But that results in this error
, but I get the error:

> Cannot lock /etc/password; try again later

When I, for example, try to create a directory in the root of the file system, I get an error:

> cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system

When I look at the different partitions with `df`, I see also that the partition of root (/) is 100% in use.

What is going on? How can I create that additional user?

Answer (score 13):

You can create a local user with the adduser command if you use the option `--extrausers`:

```
sudo adduser --extrausers test
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: I tried that one as well, but that didn't work either, got simliar error. Did you execute this in ubuntu core? Or regular ubuntu.. ?

Comment: This from a Ubuntu Core KVM instance. What error do you see?

Comment: I cannot replicate it anymore, I whiped the disk and installed mate. But the error was something about saying it wasn't able to create a usergroup for that specific user. It seems that all fails since the filesystem seems to be readonly ..

Comment: Yes, the snaps are read-only. However, each snap has its own writable space. As such, we can create local users, add network interfaces, etc. Please let us know if you have any issues with this.